# Constraint creation on a large table is too slow

Tags: constraint, postgresql-10, amazon-rds-aurora

There's a table with 723M rows, large amount of data and not partitioned. We're adding a constraint to the table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY my_table ADD CONSTRAINT partial_constraint EXCLUDE USING gist (((gid)::text) WITH =, int4range(start_sequence_number, (end_sequence_number + 1)) WITH &&) WHERE (is_valid);
```

The above constraint has been running for the past 5 days and has not finished, in the AWS insights I see that the CPU usage for the query is at 96% and IO at 4%. There's no other process running that touches my_table, I see there's an exclusive lock on the table and yet it's taking too long. When we did this in pre-production, it took couple of days.

Is there anything we can do to improve the performance off the constraint addition/see the progress?

Comment: That's too much of time I can say, Are you sure there no other sessions running? Check columns what you using have indexes or not.. If it's only exclusive lock, query may got locked waiting for transaction to finish.  Use select * from pg_locks where pid = XXX and not granted;

Comment: I have checked the pg_locks, yes, there's an exclusive lock. Since it happened in pre-production with nearly similar number of rows (720M) I saw it took 27 hours. 

Will add the indices and then retry and give an update

Comment: @CR241: After adding the indices and retrying, I'm seeing some IO activity (which wasn't there before), hopefully that implies something's happening and hope to see it finishing soon! I'll keep this posted, if the indices improved, you can move it as an answer.